# Query SUM for each day for given interval

Tags: sql-server

I have the following MS SQL Server query that returns the SUM at a certain date (2016-06-22) :

```
SELECT SUM(Value) FROM Sales 
WHERE EndDate>='2016-06-22' AND StartDate<'2016-06-22'
```

I'm trying to display the SUM for every day of a chosen interval.

What I want can be done like this:

```
SELECT
  (SELECT SUM(Value) FROM Sales WHERE EndDate>='2016-06-01' AND StartDate<'2016-06-01'), 
  (SELECT SUM(Value) FROM Sales WHERE EndDate>='2016-06-02' AND StartDate<'2016-06-02'),
  .... 
  (SELECT SUM(Value) FROM Sales WHERE EndDate>='2016-06-30' AND StartDate<'2016-06-30')
```

I want it to be done in a more elegant way.

Comment: Google and learn about the GROUP BY clause in SQL.

Comment: You can `GROUP BY StartDate, EndDate`, then - `PIVOT` with dynamic sql. Or without dynamic sql if you're constantly doing it for 30 days period.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use a UDF to create Dynamic Date Ranges (listed below).  You could also use a Numbers or Tally table as will

```
Select DateR1
      ,SomeTotal = sum(Value)
 From  Aales A
 Join (Select DateR1=RetVal,DateR2=DateAdd(DD,1,RetVal) from [dbo].[udf-Create-Range-Date]('2016-06-01','2016-06-30','DD',1)) B
   on  SalesDate Between DateR1 and DateR2 and SalesDate<DateR2
 Group By DateR1
 Order By DateR1
```

The UDF

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Create-Range-Date] (@DateFrom datetime,@DateTo datetime,@DatePart varchar(10),@Incr int)

Returns 
@ReturnVal Table (RetVal datetime)

As
Begin
    With DateTable As (
        Select DateFrom = @DateFrom
        Union All
        Select Case @DatePart
               When 'YY' then DateAdd(YY, @Incr, df.dateFrom)
               When 'QQ' then DateAdd(QQ, @Incr, df.dateFrom)
               When 'MM' then DateAdd(MM, @Incr, df.dateFrom)
               When 'WK' then DateAdd(WK, @Incr, df.dateFrom)
               When 'DD' then DateAdd(DD, @Incr, df.dateFrom)
               When 'HH' then DateAdd(HH, @Incr, df.dateFrom)
               When 'MI' then DateAdd(MI, @Incr, df.dateFrom)
               When 'SS' then DateAdd(SS, @Incr, df.dateFrom)
               End
        From DateTable DF
        Where DF.DateFrom < @DateTo
    )

    Insert into @ReturnVal(RetVal) Select DateFrom From DateTable option (maxrecursion 32767)

    Return
End

-- Syntax Select * from [dbo].[udf-Create-Range-Date]('2016-10-01','2020-10-01','YY',1) 
-- Syntax Select * from [dbo].[udf-Create-Range-Date]('2016-10-01','2020-10-01','DD',1) 
-- Syntax Select * from [dbo].[udf-Create-Range-Date]('2016-10-01','2016-10-31','MI',15) 
-- Syntax Select * from [dbo].[udf-Create-Range-Date]('2016-10-01','2016-10-02','SS',1)
```

Comment: Thanks, John! I've just modified the JOIN ON statement to fit my needs and it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can group by startdate or enddate. This assumes that either your startdate or enddate is the only date field relevant- not both. But you can adjust it if you have sales figures that span multiple days.

ex:

```
SELECT enddate,SUM(Value) FROM Sales WHERE EndDate>='2016-01-01' AND StartDate<'2016-1-03'
GROUP BY enddate
```